# Grouping results from SQL query in python to display on page

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I am running an SQL query in a views.py file and based on what values are returned I need to display different data in a column from an .html file.

If:

customer_id is not null, then the detail column should display the customer_id and name.

If:

customer_id is null, then the detail column should display the department name and description.

So, there are numbers in a database.  Some are assigned to a customer, and some are assigned to a department. The basic purpose of the table is to show a list of numbers and what they are assigned to.

```
@render_to('customer/available_numbers.html')
def AvailableNumbers(request):
    cur = NumberList()

    sql = '''
        SELECT
            cpt.number,
            cpt.call_type,
            cpt.customer_id,
            cpt.profile_id
            c.name,
            pro.department_name,
            pro.description
        FROM customerphonetable AS cpt
        LEFT OUTER JOIN customer AS c
        ON (cpt.customer_id = c.customer_id)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN profile AS pro
        ON (cpt.profile_id = pro.profile_id)
        WHERE cpt.number IS NOT NULL
        '''

    cur.execute(sql)

    rows = [dictify(row) for row in cur]

    return dict(rows=rows, cnt=len(rows))

def dictify(row):
    return dict(zip([cd[0] for cd in row.cursor_description], row))
```

NumberList() connects to the database.

The html file is set up to display the data like this:

```
{% block content %}
<table class ="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Phone Number</th>
            <th>Call Type</th>
            <th>Detail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.number }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.call_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ ???? }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tested the SQL query and it is pulling the correct data from the database.  I am getting lost on how to filter the results and correctly display the output based on the criteria.

Any suggestions?  If I am missing any info, please let me know.  Thank you.

Comment: I guess you are using MySQLdb right ? And this is Django ?

Comment: I guess that would have helped.  It's Microsoft SQL Server and yes, Django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
{% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.number }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.call_type }}</td>
        {% if row.customer_id %}
            <td>{{ row.costumer_id }}</td>
        {% else %}
            <td>{{ row.department_name }}{{ row.description }}</td>
        {% endif %}
        <td>{{ ???? }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't know what framework or ORM, if any, you are using, but you could try with variations of that like:

```
{% ifequal row.costumer_id NULL %}
{% ifequal row.costumer_id None %}
...
```

Comment: Argh.  I was trying to do something in the view.py file, and you made it so simple by just doing it in the .html file.  Thank you so much, so clear and easy!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick thanks to PepperoniPizza:

```
{% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.number }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.call_type }}</td>
            {% if row.customer_id == None %}
                <td>{{ row.department_name }}, {{ row.description }}</td>
            {% else %}
                <td>{{ row.customer_id }}, {{ row.name }}</td>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
{% end for %}
```